# Possible to set taskbar (system tray) icon for Qt console app?

Tags: c++, qt

Please consider, this is explicitly asking about an **console** application.

I know how to set the application icon, which is not the taskbar icon:

1. Qt [Setting the Application Icon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/appicon.html)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1460372/356726

For a Qt Widget application, I can set the icon in Qt Creator ( `windowIcon` ) or use `setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/the_icon.ico"));` ( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6523558/356726) )

But is there a way to set the icon for a **Qt console application**?

Comment: This is called a system tray icon in Qt parlance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the widgets module in spite of only using a console interface. Then you can use the [`QSystemTrayIcon`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSystemTrayIcon.html) class. It works fine whether it's a console application or not.

If you do not wish to use the `QSystemTrayIcon` class, then you have to resort to using winapi.

Remember that the only difference between a "console" application and non-console one on Windows is a flag set in the executable's header. There's no other fundamental difference.